# Select2 JS Loading remote data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 JS  Version 4.0.0-rc.1  and having trouble loading suggestions with remote Ajax method.

Below are the markups and code

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="selFrame1" name="selFrame1">
   <option> Select Frame </option>
</select>
```

the JavaScript Jquery

```
$('#selFrame1').select2({
        ajax: {
          url: siteUrl+"suggest/frames",
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          method:'POST',
          data: function (params) {
            return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
            };
         },
         processResults: function (data, page) {
         // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
         // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
         // alter the remote JSON data

           return {
             results: data.result
           };
          },
         cache: true
        }
});
```

The Json Result returned by server

```
{results: [{"Code":"123360000"},{"Code":"123360358"},{"Code":"123364000"},{"Code":"123400000"}], more: false }
```

I am totally not sure if I need to write specific functions to show suggestions, the comments on the Ajax section say that we should not alter the result Json data.

Now somebody please tell me what more I should to get the code working to show the suggestions.

I guess with the new version of select2 a lot of stuffs have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response is being returned as a Select2 3.x response, which is fine. We've provided the `processResults` method because of this (previously `results`) so you can modify the response on the client side.

In your case, your response includes the `results` key but your `processResponse` function is referencing a `result` key which does not exist. If you change it to something like

```
processResults: function (data, page) {
// parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
// since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
// alter the remote JSON data

  return {
    results: data.results,
    pagination: {
      more: data.more
    }
  };
},
```

Then things should start working. This also maps the existing `more` property on the response to the new `pagination` key that we migrated to in Select2 4.0.

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened , apparently I tried logging the results object inside the "processResults" module `console.log(data.results);` and nothing was logged, I doubt if the control ever reaches the processResults function. The HTTP Logs shows the json data being returned.

Comment: Thank you! For `pagination: { more: data.more }`

Answer (score 1):

Your Json response has to be like this :

```
{
  "total_count":2,
  "items": [
    {"id":"01", "name":"item 1"},
    {"id":"02", "name":"item 2"}
  ]
}
```

To work, you an id property.

Here is my config :

```
function formatRepo (repo) {
    if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

    var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'><div class='select2-result-repository__img'><img src='" + repo.img + "' width='80' height='80' /></div><div class='select2-result-repository__meta'><div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";

    markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'><div class='select2-result-repository__type'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> Type : " + repo.type + "</div><div class='select2-result-repository__usecase'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Use case : " + repo.usecase + "</div></div></div></div>";

    return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    return repo.full_name;
}

// Init select2
$(".select2").select2({
    ajax: {
        type    : "GET",
        url     : "{{ path('tag_search_js') }}",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay   : 250,
        data    : function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    placeholder: "Select a tag",
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});
```

Hope this helps !